# Fingering a chord with three pinky fingers?

Tags: piano, notation, fingering

This is the opening of the second movement of Beethoven's Pathétique Sonata (Op. 13), Schenker edition, published by Dover.

This edition seems to suggest playing each of the three notes comprising the opening chord with a pinky finger. Regrettably, I seem to lack the requisite anatomy.

Have I misunderstood what the editor is suggesting, or have I found a misprint?

[image]

Comment: The middle 5 must be a typo don't you think?

Comment: That was my guess. I first realized that the middle 3 in the second measure presumably refers to my *right* hand (after contorting my left hand unpleasantly) and only then noticed this middle 5. I'm guessing typo, but I'm still a beginner so it occurred to me that maybe I had misunderstood.

Comment: What I want to know is how do you get three pinky fingers

Comment: The whole fingering looks like it's written for a Martian. I'd recommend you to ignore it completely (unless you _are_ a Martian of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 5 on the 16th note is a misprint. Presumably it should be a 2 or 3. (Personally, I think the rest of the fingering for both hands in bar 1 is weird - but that's a different issue!)

Your edition copies the notation of the first edition (https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/50958/torat) but for an "instructive" edition with fingering, etc, it would have been better if the editor had used a bracket [ to show that the 16th notes should be played with the right hand, or rewritten the music as in the Breitkopf und Härtel edition https://imslp.org/wiki/Special:ImagefromIndex/51718/torat).

First edition:
[image]

B&H edition:
[image]